# react-native - keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide fire when screen rotate in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to make the app support both landscape and portrait. There is a strange thing that is the screen rotation will trigger keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide.

Do you know why these 2 methods are called? I have seen no purpose here to call these 2 functions

Please let me know if you have any idea. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in React native - 0.60.5.

However, the function `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardDidHide` are triggered multiple times when there is a keyboard on screen and we rotate the phone